# Login com duas tabelas

Tags: login

Gale não sei se fiz correto, tenho 2 usuários, admin e distribuidor, eu criei 2 tabelas, não sei se fiz o correto, admin tem somente id nome email e senha, já o distribuidor tem id nome email senha e outros campos mais....é correto criar 2 tabelas distintas, ou uma única tabela para os 2 usuários ?
Como fiz 2 tabelas, empaquei no seguinte:
no login fiz apenas com uma tabela...mas preciso que os 2 usuarios façam o login..

um CRUD da vida está assim :

```
public function select($fields,$table,$cond,$exec){
    $this->prepExc('SELECT '.$fields.' FROM '.$table.' '.$cond.' ',$exec);
    return $this->query;
}
```

eu tenho esta classe de login :

```
$this->log = $this->senha == $senha?
        $this->crud->select('*','administrador','WHERE email = ? && senha = ?',array($this->email,$this->cpt->setCripto($this->senha))):
        FALSE;
```

galera como fazer login neste caso de 2 tabelas ?

Comment: Porque não fez uma coluna chamada tipo = x? ai verifica qual é o tipo, e loga?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode então fazer o seguinte procedimento:

Verifique na tabela A, se e-mail e senha existe, caso retorne true, verifica se estão corretos, se retornar false, passe a próxima verificação na tabela B, ou então, retorne false.

Exemplo:

```
$consultaA = mysqli_query($conexao, "
    SELECT * FROM 
        tabela1 
    WHERE 
        email = '".$_POST['email']."' 
    AND 
        senha '".$_POST['senha']."'
");

if(mysqli_num_rows($consultaA)>0){  
    echo "Logar Administrador"; 
} else {
    $consultaB = mysqli_query($conexao, "
        SELECT * FROM 
            tabela2 
        WHERE 
            email = '".$_POST['email']."' 
        AND 
            senha '".$_POST['senha']."'
    ");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($consultaB)>0){  
        echo "Logar Usuário";       
    } else {    
        echo "Login ou senha inexistente";      
    }
}
```

Comment: Bem legal essa sua solução, vou tentar aplicar no meu código.
Agora, me dê sua sugestão, vc acha interessante criar um relacionamento de classe assim :
1 -
Tabela A - id nome email senha
Tabela B - id nome email senha telefone endereco cep ...

ou assim:
2 -
Tabela pessoa id nome email senha
Tabela admin - permissoes
Tabela distribuidor - endereco cep telefone ...

ou seja, na segunda as outras herdam da principal...?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, vc me ajudou a repensar minha lógica, decidi criar uma única tabela para os usuários, independente de quem seja ou a função que seja, utilizo a tabela USUARIO somente para o login.Obrigado amigo

Answer (score 1):

**Resolvido**
No meu caso eu decidi fazer meu sistema criando uma tabela de usuários somente para questão de login
Tabela usuarios
id  nome  email   senha

outra tabelas tipo
Tabela distribuidor
tel endereco

if($usuario->select('email','usuarios','WHERE email=?',array($email))->rowCount() > 0)

print 'email já cadastrado';